# I'm trying to create a grid using scripts and css to color it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to javascripts and to web development in it's whole but I'm trying to use a javascript to create a grid without having to type out 256 divs in my code.

[What I'm trying to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7xHC.png)

My problem is that the script doesn't add the div to my grid-container. If I manually add a div however, it becomes the right color and size.

Sorry if anything is unclear, this is my first post on this site.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsiv_Design/CSS_3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#grid-container{
width: 100vw;
display: grid;
text-align: center;
grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 2vw);
gr

id-template-rows: repeat(16, 2vw);
    justify-content: center;
    grid-gap: 0.3vw;
}
.square{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.square:nth-child(3n - 2){
    background-color: rgb(231, 142, 7);
}
.square:nth-child(3n -1){
    background-color: peachpuff;
}
.square:nth-child(3n){
    background-color: chocolate;
}
```

**JS**

```
var rows = 16;
var columns = 16;
for (i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++)
{
    var square = document.createElement('div');
    square.classList.add('square');
    document.getElementById('grid-container').appendChild(square);
}
```

Comment: Where is your JS script?  If it's at the top of the page, the `grid-container` element doesn't exist when it runs

Comment: You need to move your `<script>` tag to the `<body>` portion of your HTML, after your `grid-container` div. Otherwise when the JavaScript is executed, the `grid-container` div won't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

i don't have enough reps to comment; but i just wanted to tell you to start using `const`/`let` instead of `var`. i know it will be strange at the beginning; but you will like it in the long run.